# Combine two store files which have different reducers and store creations?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to combine two store files which have different reducers and store creations. I don't understand how I can merge my changeState reducer (which is used with createStore) with my API reducer ( which is used with configureStore).

Store 1:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const initialState = {
  sidebarShow: true,
}

const changeState = (state = initialState, { type, ...rest }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'set':
      return { ...state, ...rest }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const store = createStore(changeState)
export default store
```

Store 2:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { apiSlice } from './api/apiSlice';

  
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
    },
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => 
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
    devTools: true
  
})
```

I have tried to combine the reducers , but found that they are automatically combined when using configureStore. I also tried to create slices, which didn't work either. I'm new to Redux , any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION:

Store file:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { apiSlice } from './api/apiSlice';

 const initialState = {
        sidebarShow: true,
    }
    
    const setSideBarState = (state = initialState, { type, ...rest }) => {
        switch (type) {
          case 'set':
            return { ...state, ...rest }
          default:
            return state
        }
      }
    
    export const store = configureStore({
        reducer: {
            [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
            setSideBarState: setSideBarState
        },
        middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
            getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
        devTools: true
    
    })
```

SideBar Files:

Changed

> state.sidebarShow

to

> state.setSideBarState.sidebarShow